# React Native: How do I make my dynamically created SVG path smoother?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg

I want to add a drawing canvas to my app, and haven't found a good maintained library surprisingly. I found an article [though](https://www.obytes.com/blog/create-drawing-app) showing how to do it with SVG. All in all it works pretty well, only issue is that if I don' move my finger fairly slow, the paths come out very choppy and sharp.
Also, if my finger leaves the view, the path just starts going a little all over the place instead of closing.

This is how I create the SVG

```
function DrawingCanvas() {

  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [paths, setPaths] = useState<{ path: string[]; color: string }[]>([]);

  const onTouchMove = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
    const newPath = [...currentPath];

    //get current user touches position
    const locationX = event.nativeEvent.locationX;
    const locationY = event.nativeEvent.locationY;

    // create new point
    const newPoint = `${newPath.length === 0 ? "M" : ""}${locationX.toFixed(
      0
    )},${locationY.toFixed(0)} `;

    // add the point to older points
    newPath.push(newPoint);
    setCurrentPath(newPath);
  };
  const onTouchEnd = () => {
    const currentPaths = [...paths];
    const newPath = { path: currentPath, color };

    //push new path with old path and clean current path state
    currentPaths.push(newPath);
    setPaths(currentPaths);
    setCurrentPath([]);
  };

      return <View
        onTouchMove={onTouchMove}
        onTouchEnd={onTouchEnd}
        style={{ elevation: 5 }}
      >
        <Svg height={width - 16} width={width - 16}>
          <Path
            d={currentPath.join("")}
            stroke={color}
            fill={"transparent"}
            strokeWidth={2}
            strokeLinejoin={"round"}
            strokeLinecap={"round"}
            strokeOpacity={0.5}
          />

          {paths.length > 0 &&
            paths.map((item, index) => (
              <Path
                key={`path-${index}`}
                d={item.path.join("")}
                stroke={item.color}
                fill={"transparent"}
                strokeWidth={2}
                strokeLinejoin={"round"}
                strokeLinecap={"round"}
              />
            ))}
        </Svg>
      </View>
}

export default DrawingCanvas;
```

This is how it looks like when I try to draw a circle:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think I was doing it to treat my issue, but I was cleaning my code and splitting this component into smaller chunks and it fixed it. I guess the state updates caused it to not be smooth? Not sure, but it works flawlessly now.

EDIT: just remembering that I actually only posted the relevant part of my component, so it may seem as if there wasn't much to break into smaller components. My full component though has action buttons (clear, save, undo) and drawing controls (color, width opacity). Before, all of these lived in one component and I had my issue.
After splitting it into smaller components things work. The code in my question is a single component by itself now.

Comment: Please elaborate: your current answer is not helpful to other users with similar problems.